# code to print leap years between 1801 and 1900 using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code that outputs leap years between 1801 and 1900 and formatting the output in lines of 10 years per each line.So far here is what I have got

```
    for(int 1 == 1800; i <1900; i++200 ){
     if (i % 100 !=0 || i% 400 == 0 )
     System.out.printf("%4d %n" + i);
```

but  it is giving me compilation errors.How can I make sure my code compiles without errors???

Comment: Long answer: You need a closing brace, your loop initializer is wrong, your increment is wrong, and your print statement won't do what you expect it to do. Short answer: Check out an intro-level Java book or tutorial, that should help you get a working example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `i`, and you want to increment `i` by one. You need a comma and `printf` and your algorithm also needs to test for `% 4 == 0`. Something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1800; i < 1900; i++) {
        if ((i % 4 == 0 && i % 100 != 0) || i % 400 == 0) {
            System.out.printf("%4d%n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update

> The output is correct but it is not formatting it the way I want in lines of 10 leap years each.

Then modiy it to print with something like

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1800; i < 1900; i++) {
    if ((i % 4 == 0 && i % 100 != 0) || i % 400 == 0) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", i);
        count++;
        if (count % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The output is correct but it is not formatting it the way I want in lines of 10 leap years each.

Comment: @HighZedd Updated. For better help faster, specify the output you expect in your *question* (with an *example* maybe). It's not always clear what problem someone else is asking about.